# How to Handle Xbox Series X/S Tagging?

Tags: discussion, tags

While we don't have many questions yet about these tags (or any for the Series S right now), it seems other sources (take [Wikipedia for example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xbox_Series_X_and_Series_S)) put the Xbox Series X and Series S together, rather than having a dedicated page for each.

As far as I know, the main differences between a Series X and Series S is that the Series S has slightly less powerful hardware, and costs less (which isn't really relevant for our purposes).

Thus, should we make [xbox-series-s](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xbox-series-s) a synonym for the [xbox-series-x](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xbox-series-x) or should they have their own tag each? Should questions be specifically tagged with only one of these?

Comment: Another option is do `xbox-series-xs` (which is mentioned in the wiki and is used when talking about both), and then make both `xbox-series-x` and `xbox-series-s` synonyms

Comment: I think that the Series S and Series X problem is the same as the 2DS and 3DS, and should be handled the same way (single tag with individual consoles as synonyms).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[xbox-series-x](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xbox-series-x) and [xbox-series-s](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xbox-series-s) have been made synonyms of [xbox-series-x-series-s](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xbox-series-x-series-s).

Answer (score 6):

I personally agree with the comments - we should have a [xbox-series-xs](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xbox-series-xs) as the main tag, and have [xbox-series-x](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xbox-series-x) and [xbox-series-s](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xbox-series-s) as synonymns. This would work in the same way (and for the same reasons) as the tag [nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds).

Looks like the mods are going to have to do this one. You can't suggest synonyms unless the tags have at least 5 questions; you can't tag questions with [xbox-series-s](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xbox-series-s) or [xbox-series-xs](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xbox-series-xs), because they are too similar to [xbox-series-x](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xbox-series-x) to be created in the first place.

---

Currently, we have [xbox-series-x](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xbox-series-x), and I was unable to more appropriately tag a question [xbox-series-xs](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xbox-series-xs) because the two tags are too similar. I am also unable to suggests synonyms.

[xbox-series-x](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xbox-series-x) only has 4 associated with it; feels like we should decide and implement the changes before there are more.

Comment: I concur with this answer.

Comment: I think we would need a moderator to merge the tags for us and create any synonyms, as you need to meet the awkward synonym requirement to be able to make any.